# SQL format pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have my pivot working fine and below is the pivot table I've create

```
SET @SQL =
    '
    SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT  
               User.[Parties]
              ,User.[Accounts]
              ,User.[Amount]
              FROM User) AS BaseData

    PIVOT(
        SUM(BaseData.[Amount])
        FOR BaseData.[Parties]
        IN(' + @Parties + '     

        )
    ) AS PivotTable
    ' 
    EXEC( @SQL)
```

And an example of what I might get when the @Parties = Tom

```
Accounts     Tom
Loan         1000
Bank         3000
Bank2        1500
```

But I am having trouble formatting the numbers of the pivoted results. I want it to appear like...

```
Accounts     Tom
Loan         1,000
Bank         3,000
Bank2        1,500
```

I know the code used to do this is...

```
FORMAT(User.Amount, 'N0') AS Amount
```

But I am unable to get that in the pivot results, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Worry about the formatting of your data in your presentation layer, not in your DBMS.

Comment: The returned values are *numbers*, not strings.  You would have to convert to strings, but this is better done when you present the data, not in the database.

Comment: @SeanLange Included an example attack on this query and some mitigation options. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906115/injection-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both Larnu and Gordon pointed out, this really belongs in the presentation layer.

However, if you must, a minor change to your `BaseData` and `MAX` vs `SUM` in the PIVOT

**Example**

```
SET @SQL =
    '
    SELECT * 
     FROM (SELECT User.[Parties]
                 ,User.[Accounts]
                 ,[Amount] = format(sum(User.[Amount]),''N0'')
            FROM  User
            GROUP BY User.[Parties]
                    ,User.[Accounts]
          ) AS BaseData
    PIVOT(
        MAX(BaseData.[Amount])
        FOR BaseData.[Parties]
        IN(' + @Parties + '     
        )
    ) AS PivotTable
    ' 
    EXEC( @SQL)
```